# Bizarre error loading fixtures in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I'm having a really bizarre error when loading fixtures in Symfony2. I've used the netbeans debugger and checked the value of the variable mentioned in the error, and it is what it is supposed to be!!! Since i really have no clue about what the error can be, i'm posting the entire fixture class. The error outputted is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setGeolocation() on a non-object in /home/victor/projects/elcuadre/src/ElCuadre/OffersBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadOfferData.php on line 77

And the code is:

```
<?php

namespace ElCuadre\OffersBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\GeoLocation;
use ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\LatLng;
use ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\Offer;
use ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\Availability;
use ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\Picture;
use ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\Experience;

class LoadOfferData extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface {

    public function buildLatLngs($points) {
        $result = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($points as $point) {
            $result[] = new LatLng($point["x"], $point["y"]);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function buildGeoLocation($centerLat, $centerLong, $mapType, $type, $zoom) {
        $geoloc = new GeoLocation();
        $geoloc->setCenterLat($centerLat);
        $geoloc->setCenterLong($centerLong);
        $geoloc->setMapType($mapType);
        $geoloc->setType($type);
        $geoloc->setZoom($zoom);
        return $geoloc;
    }

    public function loadGeoLocation(ObjectManager $manager, $centerLat, $centerLong, $mapType, $type, $zoom, $points) {
        $geoloc = $this->buildGeoLocation($centerLat, $centerLong, $mapType, $type, $zoom);
        $latlngs = $this->buildLatLngs($points);
        $geoloc->setLatLngs($latlngs);
        $manager->persist($geoloc);
        foreach ($latlngs as $latlng) {
            $latlng->setGeolocation($geoloc);
            $manager->persist($latlng);
        }
        return $geoloc;
    }

    public function buildExperience($title,$location,$type){
        $exp = new Experience();
        $exp->setTitle($title);
        $exp->setDescription($title);
        $exp->setLocation($location);
        $exp->setType($type);
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $geoloc = $this->loadGeoLocation($manager, 
                5.968144043645581, -62.53726971960451,
                'HYBRID', 'Marker', 14,
    array("x" => 5.968144043645581, "y" => -62.53726971960451));
        $pictures = new ArrayCollection();
        $pictures[] = Picture::newPicture('Salto Angel A', 'Salto Angel A', 
                'Salto Angel', "imgs/content/salto angel/A.jpg");
        $pictures[] = Picture::newPicture('Salto Angel 1', 'Salto Angel 1', 
                'Salto Angel', "imgs/content/salto angel/1.jpg");
        $pictures[] = Picture::newPicture('Salto Angel 2', 'Salto Angel 2', 
                'Salto Angel', "imgs/content/salto angel/2.jpg");
        $pictures[] = Picture::newPicture('Salto Angel 3', 'Salto Angel 3', 
                'Salto Angel', "imgs/content/salto angel/3.jpg");
        $pictures[] = Picture::newPicture('Salto Angel 4', 'Salto Angel 4', 
                'Salto Angel', "imgs/content/salto angel/4.jpg");
        $pictures[] = Picture::newPicture('Salto Angel 5', 'Salto Angel 5', 
                'Salto Angel', "imgs/content/salto angel/5.jpg");

        $exp = $this->buildExperience('Salto Angel 3 días y 2 noches',
                'Salto Angel - Bolivar - Venezuela','P');
        $exp->setGeolocation($geoloc);
        foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
            $picture->setExperience($exp);
            $manager->persist($picture);
        }

        $offer = new Offer();
        $offer->setTitle('Salto Angel 3 días y 2 noches');
        $offer->setDescription('Salto Angel 3 días y 2 noches');
        $offer->setPrice(1233.43);
        $offer->setDiscount(.12);
        $offer->setStart(new \DateTime('07-04-2012'));
        $offer->setEnd(new \DateTime('09-04-2012'));
        $offer->setDescription('3 dias y 2 noches para dos personas en habitacion Suite con desayuno incluido');
        $offer->setLocation('Caracas');
        $offer->setMaxPerUser(2);
        $offer->setIsFeatured(true);
        $availabilities = new ArrayCollection();
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('07-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('08-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('09-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('10-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('11-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('12-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('13-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('14-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('15-04-2012'), 5);
        $availabilities[] = new Availability(new \DateTime('16-04-2012'), 5);
        foreach ($availabilities as $aval) {
            $offer->addAvailability($aval);
            $aval->setOffer($offer);
            $manager->persist($aval);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

}

?>
```

I checked the value of the variable `$geoloc` in the debugger, and it is what it is supposed to be (`ElCuadre\OffersBundle\Entity\GeoLocation`).

So, is there a bug in the fixture bundle? or, Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the buildExperience method, add:

```
return $exp;
```